# printf() Overflows on TI-83 Plus

Tags: c, ti-basic, z80

I'm following the tutorial [here](http://ti-84-plus.com/blog/ti-84-plus-compile-and-run-an-hello-world-c-program/). What I'm doing is to simply print out a string but it is giving me an overflow error:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

I'm compiling the C code with z88dk into a .83p file and loaded it into a TI-83p. I ran it with Doors CS7.2.

Comment: What if you made `main` a `void` method like in the tutorial? Not sure why that would solve anything, but just an observation.

Comment: @Pushkin Same. It's still showing the error.

Comment: [Maybe `printf` overflows the stack](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Tips_for_using_printf#Stack_Size)? What is the assembly? Does `puts` cause the same error?

Comment: @Cornstalks That is what I thought, but apparently after I tried removing the printf completely something is still causing the error. Probably the problem lies somewhere in the compilation process.

Comment: There's a big difference between the code linked and your code which is the linked code dose not return, but instead loops forever in a while(1) which could be an issue depending on how the calculator handles main returns.

Comment: That's a  tutorial for the TI 83 (not plus), if you use that on a TI-83+, well, I'm amazed it even get that far

Comment: Does it error when you run it without the shell, using `Asm([program name]` from the homescreen?

Comment: As @Cornstalks asked, what is the assembly it is outputting? If you can't get assembly, even the hex would be useful.